# Mysterious Murder Mystery 4

Tags: riddle, word-problem, story, mystery, situation

The sky is dark, filled with black clouds. The sun, high in the sky, still shining, trying to cut through the dark, thick, black clouds. The moon, slowly turning red, slowly taking over. You hear a howl, it seems to be coming from the thick forest that is not too far in the distance, holding on tight to her hand, trying to protect her at any costs. A werewolf jumped high off of a tree, the red moon shining behind the werewolf as it winds its hands back, ready to attack. As the beast falls towards her, an arrow appeared out of nowhere, lunging into the beasts heart. It falls to the ground, still squirming, trying to stop the pain. Slowly, the beasts stops moving, just laying there, now dead. A bunch of villagers come out of the forests asking if everything is ok, there was silence, the shock was just too great to give a response. "Oh John!" she said while still holding hands. She leaned in for a kiss, everything suddenly stopped. Words started rolling up really fast, faster than you can read them. The place just got brighter, silence than turned into many voices talking, laughing, and crying. **(Choose One)**

**Passive:**

> "The movie wasn't terrible, but it was still pretty bad. The producers did the best they could, the acting was still ok" you thought to yourself, as you got up from your seat and did a big stretch.

**Aggressive:**

> "That was one of the worst horror movies i've seen in a long time! totally not worth the money!" you thought to yourself, as you got up from your seat and did a big stretch.

You walked down the stairs, walking towards the exit. As you leave through the exit, a bright light just hit you, the front lobby of the movie theatre is now packed. Lobby filled with the young and the old, male and female, friends and family, all having fun and enjoying the day. You exit the theatre and start walking towards  your car, when all of a sudden you receive a call. "RING RING RING RING RING!" your cell phone goes, you pick it up, "Hello?" you said. "Sorry to bother you, but we have a situation" said one of the officers, you rush towards your car as the officer tells you the location. As you drive to the destination, you hear on the radio "Cloudy with a chance of rain today, but as for the rest of the week, SUNNY, SUNNY, SUNNY! Back to you Steve. Thank you Margaret, we do have a collison on Main St. so there might be a jam up.", you realised that you are current on Main St. and will probably get to the collison and the traffic jam soon. "Should i take a detour or stay on Main St.?" you wondered to yourself. **(Choose One)**

**Detour:**

> You decided to take a detour, trying to cut through the traffic. As you are taking the detour, you get stuck in traffic. "There is currently a big jam up on Duke St. as well, looks like everybody is trying to take a detour around Main St." you hear on the radio. You give a big sigh and went along with the traffic.

**Main St:**

> You decided to stay on Main St, you didn't seem to have noticed a slow down. It is slower than usual, but the traffic is still moving. You didn't seem to mind because the traffic jam up wasn't that bad.

When you finally arrive at the crime scene, everyone is already there like usual. There is a crowd of people trying to see what is going on, as some of the officers are trying to keep pedestrians and news reporters behind the yellow police line. You squeeze your way through the crowd of people, and cross the police line. As you got closer, you see a body lying on the floor, "Glad you can make it, i hope the traffic wasn't too bad for you" said one of the other detectives smiling. you didn't think much about it, because you knew that she always likes to joke around and get on your nerve. You walk up to the body, you noticed that the man has been stabbed twice in the back, blood everywhere on the ground, staining the walkway. The body reeked of a foul odor, like garbage or trash.The man has short black hair, wearing a black t-shirt and red pants. On the victim is a folded piece of paper, you unfold the piece of paper. On it is a picture of a mouse, "This might be the killers calling card or something" you thought to yourself. Near the body are a few yellow cones, you walk up to them. **(Choose Two)**

**Clue 1:**

> You see a pair of yellow running shoes. With further investigation, you found that the shoes are a size 15 for men.

**Clue 2:**

> You see a wallet, and inside the wallet you find a driver's license. The mans name is Terry G Delf, 5' 5" in height, born on November 18. You take a closer look to see that the year of Terry's birthday has been scratched out. You pondered about this for a minute.

**Clue 3:**

> You see a pair of dirty white gloves right beside yellow cone, the gloves seems to have been used.

As you started walking towards the last yellow cone, you hear "HEY!", You turn around to see what the commotion is about. You see that one of the officers has been pushed down, and reporters rushing towards you to see the crime scene. The reporters quickly set up the cameras and mics to film as much as they can, the officers tried to stop them from disturbing the crime scene. All of a sudden, you hear someone scream! You see a bunch of mice running everywhere, most of them running towards the body. Citizens, reporters, officers, and detectives all started running around. Trying to either get away from the mice, or trying to stop others from disturbing the crime scene. You see mice running over the evidence, nibbling on it. The mice are probably attracted to the odor, you thought to yourself.

The scene is now a mess, with everyone still running, pushing, and screaming. You knew that there won't be any evidence left, other than what you have already saw. As you got out of the crowd, you noticed that on the ground is a cage, the door opened, nothing inside the cage. "Seems like sabotage" you muttered to yourself. You looked around to see if you can catch anyone that is suspicious, but no one in particular caught your eye.

You decide to head back to your office, ponder about the situation and start your report. Couple of hours has passed, you are in your office writing up the report when you hear a knock on your door. "Come in" you said, your assistant opens the door "Your needed at the intersection of Key St. and Peele Road". As you arrive, the officers are setting up the police line and securing the middle of the road. You enter the crime scene to see that there is another dead body lying on the ground, and a detective setting up some yellow cones around. You walk up to the body, the man is wearing a orange shirt, and blue jeans. The man also has black hair, and brown eyes. Upon closer investigation, you notcied that there is a red mark around the mans neck and beside him is a folded piece of paper. You unfold the paper to find a picture of a dog on it, You then walk over to the yellow cones, trying to gather more information about the crime. **(Choose Two)**

**Clue 4:**

> You see a brown wallet, you open it up trying to find a piece of identification. You find the mans driver license, his name is George Y Logan, 6' 7", and date of birth is May 23. The year of which the man is born on is scratched out.

**Clue 5:**

> You see a simple dog leash, not one of those dog leashes where the owner can just click a button and it pulls the dog back in, it was just a simple dog leash.

**Clue 6:**

> You see a pair of dirty white gloves right beside the yellow cone, the gloves seems to have been used.

As you were examining the clue, you hear a loud honk coming from an incoming truck. The driver repeatedly honking as if he is trying to warn others of something, the truck does not seem to be slowing down. People a head of you started running away, trying to avoid the truck as it speeds pass everything and crushing whatever is in its path. You jumped and rolled out of the way, just as the truck was about to hit you. The truck swirves, and tips over, crashing into everything infront of it, including the remainding evidence and an electrical post. As you got up, you noticed that the as tank is leaking, the gasoline rapidly flowing out to the street. The gasoline, flowing closer and closer towards the live electrical cord from the post. One of the officers warns everyone to evacuate as the gasoline is about to touch the live cord, other officers helping the driver out of the truck as fast as possible.

You started running away from the truck, as you look back, you see the gasoline just about to touch the wire. There is an loud explosion, "BOOM!". As you got up from the ground, you see that the truck, as well as, its surroundings engulfed in flames. You hear sirens coming from down the street, you knew it was the fire trucks and ambulances. You watched the fire burning, knowing that the evidence is now gone. "Is it just me, or do i have the worst luck?" you said to yourself. As the fire fighters try to put out the flames, you walk towards your car and headed home.

You arrive home, showered, made dinner, and is now relaxing and watching some tv. You are flipping through the guide menu, trying to search for what to watch next on the 9:30 PM time slot. "RING RING RING" goes your phone, you knew that it will not be good news. "Hello?" you said, "There has been a murder at 1890 Fountain St, it's the house with a blue garage door, you can't miss it" as the officer on the other line ends the call. You rush over to the location, when you arrive, cop cars are already surrounding the whole area of the house. You enter through the front door, you noticed that there are people on the ground, all bleeding heavily, blood splattered everywhere. two are sitting on the couch slouched over, one of them are laying on there stomach, and the other two were on the floor, backs againsts the floor. They were all young, you estimated them around the age of 19-23 years old, and have all been shot with a gun.

All of a sudden, one of the bodies moved, breathing heavily, gasping like she was trying to tell us something. "WE HAVE A SURVIVOR! WE NEED MEDICAL ATTENTION IMMEDIATELY!" yelled one of the officers, 4 paramedics rushed in, all surrounding the young female, trying to save her life. They wheeled her outside and onto the ambulance, and rushed to the hospital. You noticed that everyone had their own unique characteristics, some had black hair, some had blonde, and others had brunette/brown. They were of all different sorts of race, but you could not specifically tell what race they were.

You decide to look around the house, you noticed that they have decorated the place like they were having a party. There are drinks on the living room table, as well as snacks. The tv was on, it seems like some of them were playing with the gaming console. There was glow sticks on the ground, table, and couch. In the kitchen, there was more food and drinks, on one of the counters there were plates, cups, and utensils. Each plate and cup had names on it, probably to be able to tell whos plate or cup belonged to who. You read the names on each cup from left to right, Suzy F Guido, Hank F Tay, Joe L Kring, Katie H Yu, Vicki B Bee, and Ann E Mole. Each plate had some chips, dipping sauce, and a slice of pizza, while the cups had beverages in them, all but the last set. You went back to the living room to see if any of them had their wallets, but none of them had one.

You went to check every other room, but none of them were disturbed. It seems like the party was only intended for the living room and the kitchen. It didn't seem like anything else was disturbed. After searching through the house, you left the crime scene and headed home. When you got home, you went straight to bed. You immediately fell asleep due to the exhausting day you just had. You get woken up by your alarm clock, you get up and give a big stretch. You yawn, "That was a great sleep, i needed that" you said to yourself. You started to get ready for your day, you brush your teeth, take a shower, got dressed, and made breakfast. As you head out the door, you realised that you are ahead of schedule, so you decide to take the nice scenic route to work today.

As you were driving along the nice view of the river, you see that there are cop cars around this one area of the river, you decide to go check it out. Upon arrival you see many officers talking and pointing at something in the water. You ask one of the officers what is going on, "There a body over there in the river, and it seems like blood everywhere surrounding the body". You focus on the body in the distance, you see that the person is not moving, the person is also wearing a blue shirt, white pants, and has blonde to white hair. On top of the person is a piece of paper, you recognize the paper and how it is folded. You knew that this was another murder by the same person, you noticed that there are 3 objects near the body, but the body and the objects are quickly sinking.

You quickly jump into the river and swim as fast as you can towards the body, as you get closer, the body and objects are sinking deeper and deeper. You got there just in time to be able to grab the piece of paper and the body, one of the officers threw you a life jacket and you put it on the body. You look around to see that the objects are still sinking, you remembered that you were never too good at swimmming and the objects are almost too deep for you to reach. You take a deep breathe and started diving after the objects, you know you can't reach all of them so you decided to go after one of the object. **(Choose One)**

**Object 1:**

> You grabbed one of the objects, and started swimming back to the surface, once you reach the surface you gasp for air. You swim back to shore, as the officers help pull you up. You look at the object you have grabbed, it is a wallet. Inside the wallet was a drivers license, The mans name is Doug R Peul, 5' 5" in height, and date of birth is June 9. The year is scratched out.

**Object 2:**

> You grabbed one of the objects, and started swimming back to the surface, once you reach the surface you gasp for air. You swim back to shore, as the officers help pull you up. You look at the object you have grabbed, it is a small blue hat. It is so small that it would not actually fit on anyones head.

**Object 3:**

> You grabbed one of the objects, and started swimming back to the surface, once you reach the surface you gasp for air. You swim back to shore, as the officers help pull you up. You look at the object you have grabbed, it is a red bow tie. There is nothing special about it, it is just a regular red bow tie.

You remembered that you grabbed the piece of paper as well. As you carefully opened the piece of paper, making sure it does not rip, you see there is a picture of a duck on it. You walk over to the body, you see there are two paramedics there beside the body. As you got closer, one of the paramedics said that he is dead and the cause of death is drowning. Still exhausted, you went back to your car and sat there for a little while to catch your breath. "And i just took a shower too" you muttered to yourself. Out of leads, You call the General Hospital to see if the survivor from the party is awake, maybe that person can give us a lead. "Sorry, but the patient has not awoken yet and will need rest for another week or so". Just when things looked bad, you recieve a call from the police department, telling you that they have got some suspects. You quickly rush over to the police department.

when you arrive, you see that there are 3 suspects lined up, ready for interrogation. The first suspect is male, 35 years of age, has black hair, beard, and green eyes. "My name is Peter P Anne, i am an art teacher. I didn't commit any murders, i have been working". The second suspect is a female, 38 years old, has red hair, beautiful, and blue eyes. "My name is Alice W Derland, i am a performer. I did not kill anyone, i work late nights, and get home in the morning. I worked during the days the murder happened". The last suspect is a male, 27 years old, black hair, and has a moustache. "My name is Walt D Esnie, i didn't commit any crimes. I work in a studio as a helper, so i couldn't have killed anyone".

You ponder about all the information at the crime scenes, and the house party. You thought hard about it, then it hit you! You told the police to go arrest the murderers.

Who is the murderers?

Comment: +1 for silly suspect names. I see what you did there.

Comment: Please state what options you have chosen, and hide your answer in the yellow hidden box

Comment: I think I know who it is from just two clues at each scene, but that word-problem tag is telling me there's something more to look for here.

Comment: I'm glad to see you're still doing these. I like how fleshed out they are

Comment: I have the [cloud-to-butt extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/cloud-to-butt-plus/apmlngnhgbnjpajelfkmabhkfapgnoai?hl=en) on, and sometimes get confused like here when I see "The sky is dark, filled with black butts. The sun, high in the sky, still shining, trying to cut through the dark, thick, black butts." Sir Mix-A-Lot would be proud.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I looked at Clues 1 & 2, 5 & 6, and Object 1. I also took the detour, sigh.

The party murders were committed by:

> Peter P Anne.

Evidence:

> All of the victims at the party were young, but none of the suspects were. He is a teacher, so would have the circumstances to befriend a group of young people. Also his name hints that he would hang out with young people.

And

> There were plates and cups for 6 guests, but only 5 of them had been used. There were 5 victims. The unused plate and cup belonged to  Ann E Mole (animal). Since Peter's last name was Anne, that was probably his nickname among the group. The name being a woman's name was a red herring pointing to Alice W Derland.

The mouse/dog/duck murders were committed by:

> Walt D Esnie.

Evidence:

> Having that name no doubt inspired a life-long obsession with Disney characters. He chose victims with the same birthdates as Disney characters, then dressed them to match. Mickey Mouse (November 18, debut of Steamboat Willie; black shirt, red pants, yellow shoes), Donald Duck (June 9th, his debut in The Wise Little Hen; blue shirt, white pants, white hair), and Goofy (orange shirt, blue pants, a leash, and white gloves; no birthday in my clues).

Comment: +1 for the closes answer! you are soooo close! you are about 97% correct, but there is a small thhing that is wrong

Comment: Oh I hope it's not the part about the nickname. I was so proud of that!

Comment: My answer is that Peter P Anne and Ann E Mole did not have a connection, Ann E Mole did commit the crime in the house and Walt D Esnie committed the three murders. They were meant to be separate murders, two separate cases. But somehow you linked peter and ann together lol. +1 & Correct answer

Answer (score 2):

The murderer is

> You edited it to imply multiple murderers, so I guess it's all three? Peter P Anne = Peter Pan, a Disney movie character; Alice W Derland = Alice In Wonderland, also a Disney movie character; and Walt D Esnie is Walt Disney himself.

I chose options: Aggressive, Main Street, Clues 1, 3, 4, 6, and Object 1

Clues 1 and 3, along with the mouse picture imply

> Mickey Mouse.  He wears white gloves and large yellow shoes and is a mouse.

Clues 4 and 6, along with the dog picture imply

> Goofy.  Most of the details from clue 4 don't mean much to me, but Goofy is tall, and he wears white gloves

Object 1, along with the duck picture imply

> Donald Duck.  None of the details from the object really mean anything to me, but the duck picture along with the fact that the body was in the water, along with the previous clues would indicate Donald Duck.

Other things

> I'd guess that the movie is Beauty and the Beast?  And the traffic problems on Main St is the usual Disney park parade.  And the party would be some kid's birthday party at the Disney park.

Comment: slight change in the last small sentence and question

Comment: Edited my answer.

Comment: there are multiple murderers, but you are not correct in choosing them

Answer (score 2):

This one was slightly easier than the last two. The murderers are

> Walt D Esnie and Peter P Anne.

Here are my explanations along with the clue choices I used to arrive at those conclusions.

Scene 1, with the mouse calling card:

> Dirty white gloves, and size 15 shoes that would be far too big for a short 5'5" victim. Points towards "Mickey Mouse". The victim is dressed like this as well.

Scene 2, with the dog calling card:

> Strangulation with a dog leash, and white gloves again. Points towards a "Goofy" motif, as the victim was dressed like this as well.

Scene 3, the party:

> This is the nail in the coffin. Walt said he works at a studio. You notice that all the partygoers are all over the living room, while there are *full plates* of snacks and such in the kitchen. Why would that be? If the party was in full swing, the food would be splattered all over the living room floor. The last beverage cup being empty would likely be from Walt rushing to leave the scene once he heard the authorities coming.

Scene 4, the body in the river:

> The duck calling card and the red bow tie, pointing to a "Donald" motif. The victim, again, was dressed like Donald Duck.

Clearly, the killers work for

> a Disney Imagineering studio, and decided to go on a serial murdering spree. Walt staged the party and came up with the Disney motif idea, while Peter likely created the wardrobe and calling cards, something that would be easy for an art teacher.

Comment: slight change in the last small sentence and question

Comment: Edited, although it's hard to pin more than one.

Comment: you are very close to the right answer

Comment: So then what you're saying is either a) the person I didn't mention is correct,  b) all three of them are correct, c) my initial guess was completely incorrect.

Comment: i can't say or it would give it away, maybe go back and read it more carefully?

Comment: I don't know. I've read it pretty carefully, and the names seem like red herrings but the word-problem implies that they aren't. It's like the killers are agents of the Riddler.

Comment: Hint: try to connect the party murder to the other murders

Comment: Can't really tell how. The victims at the party were all missing wallets; the other victims weren't. The victims at the party (which was likely staged) were killed by gunshot; the other victims were stabbed. The names also have ostensibly no connection whatsoever.

Comment: ok, so from what you said, there is no connection between the two. Maybe they are separate cases? hint hint